# Convert a C integer power function to MIPS assembly language: taking args and returning a value, using registers for C variables

Tags: c++, assembly, mips

I want to transfer this code to MIPS

```
// Returns b times a, or a^b
int power(int a, int b) {
   int result = 1;
   for(int i=b; i>0; --i)
      result*=a;
   return result;
}
```

these are my attempts

```
power:
      li $a0, 1             
      move $v0, $a0       
loop: beq $v0, $zero, exit  
      mul $v0, $v0, $a0   
      addi $v0, $v0, -1    
      j loop               
exit: jr $ra
```

Comment: What is your question?  Are you asking for a code review?

Comment: Why, out of interest?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if my answer is wrong

Comment: Well it's a horrible approach. Exponentation by squaring will be faster.

Comment: How can your function return a value, when it has a `void` return type (and the parameters are passed by copy)?

Comment: Run your answer in a MIPS simulator like MARS so you can single-step it and look at registers change.  That will identify the obvious bugs like using the same 1 register for 3 C variables, and not using one of the inputs at all.  Then, if you get to a point where you can't see a problem or can't identify the fix, you can include a proper [mcve] and ask about that.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I edited the question to fix that obvious C bug (and a missing semicolon); clearly the question isn't about that.  But yeah, starting from valid C is important.  (Of course it's easy to check by using an actual compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/bvPdK1ndf like gcc `-O3 -fno-delayed-branch` which defaults to `-march=mips32` to allow mul instead of mult/mflo).

Answer (score 4):

It's close but you've made some mistakes.

Let's start with what we know: on entry parameter variable `a` is in `$a0`, and parameter variable `b` is in `$a1`.

Your code immediately overwrites `$a0`, so access to the original value of parameter variable `a` is lost.  Further, the code never uses `$a1`, so doesn't reference parameter variable `b`.  (Both of these in contrast to what the C code does.)

This function must place the return value in `$v0` by the time of function exit (this can be done implicitly by using `$v0` for `result` or by using another register instead and copying that into `$v0` just before function exit.)

Your assembly instructions are sensible, but the register usages are not.

So, fundamentally, you need to revisit your mapping of logical variables in C, including:

- parameters,
- local variables and return values

to the physical storage in assembly language.  Don't guess at it — use methodology, for example, annotate on paper or in comments which register is being used for what purpose.  (Also remember that one physical storage location cannot hold two live variables at the same time!)

For this function, these variable mappings should be straightforward (this function is not complicated by further function calls or other requirements for a stack frame).

Once you have good mappings, the code for statements and expressions should simply follow those mappings, and then it should be correct.